# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when extracting from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm receiving this `TypeError`:

```
if 'Stack 6' in placement():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
```

Converting it to an integer in my `for`-each statement doesn't work, and I can't change any of the values in the list.

I cannot work out why this returns the `TypeError`:

```
game = [['Stack 6', 'Suit D', 9, 6],
  ['Stack 4', 'Suit B', 5, 0]]

for instructions in game:
    for placement in instructions:
        if 'Stack 6' in placement():
            print(placement)
```

Yet, this similar piece of code doesn't return any error:

```
elements = [['he', 'ne', 'Ar', 'Kr'],
    ['F', 'Cl', 'Br', 'I']]

for family in elements:
    for symbol in family:
        if 'a' in symbol.lower():
            print(symbol)
```

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`placement` is not a function. It is a `string`. Putting parentheses after an object tells python to call that object, which it cannot do for a string. Remove the parentheses to fix the code.

The code with `symbol.lower()` works because `lower()` is a function which can be called in order to return something.

[Here's a handy link](https://arvimal.blog/2017/08/09/callables-in-python/) to explain in more detail what callables are in python.